# What is the best structure for communicating between Fragments in android?

Tags: android, callback, fragment, communication

When there are some different fragments in a Activity, What way is the best and more safe for communicating between fragments?
I used `callback` but I passed it by constructors, now I get some crashes.
I think `null callbacks` are cause of crashes, when application is in background and then user return to application, callback is null.
There is big problem, when I has a lot of fragments in a Activity, implementing callbacks in the Activity is a difficult and confusing way.
I have tested `EventBus` but my purpose is just one fragment and It's a little harsh, and also may be fragment needs to get data from parent fragment.
Do you know a better way?
[my structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfaLk.png)
I have many fragments A, B, C ,... . When fragment A is updated ,I want to update fragment B too, and this is the same for other fragments , when updating fragment C, D should be updated too and so on.
if I want to use interfaces, I should write many interfaces. Is there any other suggestion?

Comment: You can use all your communation between fragment via container activity

Comment: you can  use`Interface `

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Bundle` class for this.

```
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putString("my_value", "hello world");
 Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
 fragment1.setArguments(args);
```

In another fragment to receive the value:

```
String requiredValue = getArguments().getString("my_value");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (getActivity() instanceof YourActivityName)
{
       ((YourFragment2Name)getActivity()).variable);
}
```

//make sure variable in YourFragment2Name should be public.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends upons your expected scenario.

```
Using Interface 
Using Broadcast Receivers 
Using Container Activity 
Using EventBus or Alternative Libs 
Using Observers (Rx Pattern)
```

For Interface Communication Please check

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    interface FragmentCallback {
       void onClickButton(MyFragment fragment);
    }    

    private FragmentCallback mCallback;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            mCallback.onClickButton(this);
        }
    }
}
```

And In Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragment.FragmentCallback {

    //onCreate



    @Override
    public void onClickButton(MyFragment fragment) {
       // Do your Task
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a regular pattern for implementing interfaces in a activity that my codes keeps its clean.

Comment: I've explained bit more.